# How to protect a 12v lead acid battery from a short circuit?

Tags: 12v, short-circuit, lead-acid

Is there a board that protects lead acid batteries from a short circuit. The capacity of my battery is 4,7Ah. My circuit is consuming about 3 amps.

Comment: A fuse, perhaps?

Comment: Don't connect the battery leads together and don't make a board that causes the leads to connect together directly via copper traces.

Comment: put a bulb in series so that a short just lights the bulb directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put a fuse in series with the battery, like so.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhrUAm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It really doesn't get much simpler than that.

Comment: what would be the value of the fuse

Comment: If you mean the current rating, pick one slightly above your designed operating point.

Comment: so like a  5A fuse

Comment: You should use a fuse rated a little higher than the maximum current you expect the load to draw.  Since we don't know what sort of load you have, we can't suggest a suitable rating.

Comment: how much current does a short circuit produce

Comment: It depends on the battery. Generally a _lot_.

Comment: Im using this battery www.motobatt.com/download_pdf.php?p=91

Comment: And can i do this without replacing a fuse every time

Comment: Well, for one thing, if you're _expecting_ a short circuit to happen often, you're probably doing something wrong. If you want to not have to replace fuses when the protection trips, you can use a circuit breaker or a polyfuse.